# expected first layer to have x dimensions but got an array with shape y

Tags: image, tensorflow, classification, tensorflow.js

(I am just starting tensorflow.js on node)
I have been searching the web up and down for an answer.
**The confusion**
I have image data from `image1 = tf.fromPixels(img)` and I tried inputting it along with other image data to `xs = tf.tensor([image1, image2])`. The confusion is no matter how I input a bunch of images into `xs` for `model.fit`, the program outputs errors described below.

**What I already tried**
When I run the program I get the error `Error: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_Conv2D1_input to have 4 dimension(s). but got array with shape 4,1`
I know for a fact that I am not inputting the xs correctly. I read some articles online relating to how you need to input the array in a fashion like `tf.tensor([[0.2, 0.1], [0.2, 0.4]]);` and some batching of images of some sort. I looked at articles showing that for images, you need another set of layers:

```
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
    inputShape: [scaleHeight, scaleWidth, 3],
    kernelSize: 5,
    filters: 8,
    strides: 1,
    activation: 'relu',
    kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling'
}));
model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
    poolSize: [2, 2],
    strides: [2, 2]
}));

model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
    kernelSize: 5,
    filters: 16,
    strides: 1,
    activation: 'relu',
    kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling'
}));

model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
    poolSize: [2, 2],
    strides: [2, 2]
}));

model.add(tf.layers.dense({ // Output
    units: 2,
    kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling',
    activation: 'softmax'
}));
model.compile({loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy', optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.1), metrics: ['accuracy']});
```

Well I tried inputting that in, tried converting them into typedarray format, tried a lot of things. I am pretty lost on coming up with a proper xs variable for multiple images turned to tensors by `tf.fromPixels(canvas)` for `model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 100, options....});`

**Code:**

```
var tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
var cv = require('canvas');
var {Image, createCanvas, ImageData} = cv;
tf.disableDeprecationWarnings();

var scaleWidth = 16;
var scaleHeight = 16;

function getImage(path){
    var img = new Image();
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        img.onload = function(){
            var element = createCanvas(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
            var ctx = element.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            ctx.scale(scaleWidth/img.width, scaleHeight/img.height);
            //resolve(Array.from(tf.fromPixels(element).flatten().dataSync()));

            resolve(tf.fromPixels(element));
        };
        img.src = path;
    });
}

var log = function(input){console.log(input)};

const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
    inputShape: [scaleHeight, scaleWidth, 3],
    kernelSize: 5,
    filters: 8,
    strides: 1,
    activation: 'relu',
    kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling'
}));
model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
    poolSize: [2, 2],
    strides: [2, 2]
}));

model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
    kernelSize: 5,
    filters: 16,
    strides: 1,
    activation: 'relu',
    kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling'
}));

model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
    poolSize: [2, 2],
    strides: [2, 2]
}));

model.add(tf.layers.dense({ // Output
    units: 2,
    kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling',
    activation: 'softmax'
}));
model.compile({loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy', optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.1), metrics: ['accuracy']});

(async function(){
    var cats = [], bland = [];

    cats[0] = await getImage('cats/0.jpeg');
    cats[1] = await getImage('cats/1.jpeg');
    bland[0] = await getImage('bland/0.png');
    bland[1] = await getImage('bland/1.png');

    var testCats = await getImage('c.jpeg');
    var testBland = await getImage('b.jpeg');

    var xs = tf.tensor([cats[0], cats[1], bland[0], bland[1]]); // confusion occurs here

    for(var c = 0; c < 10; c++){
        var result = await model.fit(xs, tf.tensor([[0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0]]), {epochs: 100});
        console.log(result.history.loss[0]);
    }
})();
```

And after I ran it, I expected to at least log the loss of the model but it thrown this error: 
`Error: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_Conv2D1_input to have 4 dimension(s). but got array with shape 4,1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code the data passed in to your model doesn't have the same shape as the model first layer inputShape.

How to go about solving the issue ?

- check the data.shape.

```js
console.log(xs.shape) // it will return (4,1)
```

- compare with the inputShape

  The data shape should one dimension higher than the inputShape (one more dimension for batchsize)

```js
    // Does `xs.inputShape.slice(1) ===[Scaleheight, scaleWidth,3]` ? 

    shape1 = xs.inputShape.slice(1)
    shape2 = [Scaleheight, scaleWidth,3]
    const same = (shape1.length == shape2.length) && shape1.every(function(e, i) {
    return e === shape2[i]; 
});
```

If they are not equal, there are two ways to get the problem resolved

- Reshaping the data if possible,using `tf.reshape`, `tf.slice`, `tf.expandDims()`, ...
- Or simply changing the inputShape to be equal to our data shape

---

In your case here there is a clear mismatch between the inputShape and the data shape.

First thing first, the way you create your xs is wrong. Actually, xs has the shape (4, 1) with NaN values. It is as if you created a `tf.tensor` with an array of tensors. You can create the xs this way:

```
xs = tf.concat([...cats, ...blands], 0)
```

However it is not sure if this will solve completely the issue. You need to iterate over the step outlined above,ie, check the shape of xs, compare with the inputShape and so on ...

Comment: Great constructive answer! The only problem is no matter how I reshape it, the shape is going to be [64, 16, 3]. I tried making it so that I was batching 4 images, so it was going to be a 4d tensor shape: [4, 16, 16, 3]. I tried reshaping it using `xs.reshape(4, 16, 16, 3)`, tried `xs.as4D(4, 16, 16, 3)`, but it keeps getting turning  to [64, 16, 3]. The error: `Error: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_Conv2D1_input to have 4 dimension(s). but got array with shape 64,16,3`

Comment: @SimonCheng, `tf` operators are not inplace operators meaning that the they don't change the tensor on which they are applied. If you want to change the shape of `xs`, consider reassigning to the tensor the result of the operation like the following: `xs = xs.reshape(4, 16, 16, 3)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I fixed it by `xs = xs.reshape(4, 16, 16, 3);` but instead of the error that says `but got array with shape 64,16,3` now it says `Error when checking target: expected dense_Dense1 to have 4 dimension(s). but got array with shape 4,2` even though I logged `console.log(xs.shape);` which outputted `[4, 16, 16, 3]`. What is wrong here now? The shape is good.

Comment: I see the problem, its the ys thats causing the issue. Do you have any ideas what to put for the ys? Its the labels right?

Comment: Since this question is directly not related to the first one, I will suggest openning a new thread for it. It is good to have one thread for a single issue :)