# Tensorflow.js: Error when checking target ... expected layer to have n dimensions

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I'm just starting out with Tensorflow.js, and am trying to build a simple model that takes as input 28 by 28 arrays (each representing a picture). Something isn't connecting quite right though. Running the snippet below, I get:

```
errors.ts:48 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error when checking target: expected dense_Dense1 to have 2 dimension(s). but got array with shape 100,28,28
    at new e (errors.ts:48)
    at Od (training.ts:147)
    at e.standardizeUserData (training.ts:1133)
    at training_tensors.ts:427
    at common.ts:14
    at Object.next (common.ts:14)
    at common.ts:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at op (common.ts:14)
    at kd (training_tensors.ts:408)
```

Here's the code itself:

```js
// build the model
var input = tf.input({shape: [28,28]})
var h1 = tf.layers.reshape({targetShape: [28*28]}).apply(input)
var h2 = tf.layers.dense({units: 100}).apply(h1)
var model = tf.model({inputs: input, outputs: h2})
model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError', lr: 0.0001})
model.summary();

// get training data and train
var trainX = tf.ones([100,28,28]);

model.fit(trainX, trainX, {
  batchSize: 10,
  epochs: 1,
})
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tensorflow/1.1.2/tf.min.js'></script>
```

What confuses me is that the `model.summary()` call returns:

```
_________________________________________________________________
layer_utils.ts:152 Layer (type)                 Output shape              Param #   
layer_utils.ts:64 =================================================================
layer_utils.ts:152 input1 (InputLayer)          [null,28,28]              0         
layer_utils.ts:74 _________________________________________________________________
layer_utils.ts:152 reshape_Reshape1 (Reshape)   [null,784]                0         
layer_utils.ts:74 _________________________________________________________________
layer_utils.ts:152 dense_Dense1 (Dense)         [null,100]                78500     
layer_utils.ts:74 =================================================================
layer_utils.ts:83 Total params: 78500
layer_utils.ts:84 Trainable params: 78500
layer_utils.ts:85 Non-trainable params: 0
layer_utils.ts:86 _________________________________________________________________
```

This suggests the reshape layer should be passing an array with shape (batch, 784) to the dense layer, but the error suggests otherwise.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Any suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when checking input: expected dense\_Dense1\_input to have x dimension(s). but got array with shape y,z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326770/error-when-checking-input-expected-dense-dense1-input-to-have-x-dimensions-b) and [expected first layer to have x dimensions but got an array with shape y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54701704/expected-first-layer-to-have-x-dimensions-but-got-an-array-with-shape-y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My input had shape (batch, 28, 28), while the model output had shape (batch, 100). However, I asked my model to predict `trainX` given inputs `trainX` (the second and first arguments to `model.fit`, respectively).

To fix this I just needed to update the shape of the values to be predicted to (batch, 100):

```
// build the model
var input = tf.input({shape: [28,28]})
var h1 = tf.layers.reshape({targetShape: [28*28]}).apply(input)
var h2 = tf.layers.dense({units: 17}).apply(h1)
var model = tf.model({inputs: input, outputs: h2})
model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError', lr: 0.0001})
model.summary();

// get training data and train
var trainX = tf.ones([100,28,28]),
    trainY = tf.ones([100, 17])

model.fit(trainX, trainY, {
  batchSize: 10,
  epochs: 1,
}).then(function() {
  console.log( model.predict(trainX).dataSync() )
})
```